# Component to draw in a chart and gain data points from the drawing

Tags: xaml, charts, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am wondering if there is any (Win8 Metro-styled) WinRT/XAML component that can be used to determine data from a drawing in a prefilled chart.
The control should initially display a chart but the user should be able to draw a new line, bar etc. in it or to continue the existing series. This drawing should then be used to gather the underlying data points.

I guess one could lay a canvas over a chart and use this to draw but then it's rather complicated to apply the axis values of the charts afterwards.

Comment: Is it WPF you want or WinRT/XAML? That's two different things.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I mean WinRT/XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no chart controls available in WinRT. You can draw something using any APIs you choose - Rectangles, Image+WriteableBitmap etc. and handle pointer events to draw or adjust your data points.

Answer (score 1):

Telerik has preview controls available:

http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-metro.aspx